# how to set multiple values in Antd Filters:[{}] in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd, use-effect, react-functional-component, ant-design-pro

i want to add multiples values in the Filters: {} so that i can filter that. is this possible or not?

This is the column Part where I'm filtering:

```
{
      title: 'Provider',
      dataIndex: 'provider',
      key: 'provider',
      width: 120,
      filters: [
        { text: 'Firebase', value: 'Firebase' },
        { text: 'Facebook', value: 'facebook.com , faceBook' },
        { text: 'Google', value: 'Google' },
        { text: 'Password', value: 'password' },
      ],
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.provider.includes(value),
      ellipsis: true,
    },
```

This is the UI screen shot:

[image]

Comment: what final data you want ?